# difference between storage requirements of null and empty string database

Tags: database

Let us put aside the meaning of null and empty string conceptually, I would like to know which is beneficial in terms of storage.

Comment: I am mostly interested in mysql but general overview is also fine.

Comment: Thank you I will. I was just wondering what it is

Comment: I meant other questions, so that it'll help the community.

Answer (score 0):

Columns which can contain NULL values usually uses one bit extra per row to mark if it's NULL or not. This may depend on the database system though; SQLite for example have datatypes for each value, so null values differ from string values on a more fundamental level.

For MySQL, consider [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/dynamic-format.html) in the manual:

> The expected row length for dynamic-sized rows is calculated using the
>   following expression:
>
> ```
> 3
> + (number of columns + 7) / 8
> + (number of char columns)
> + (packed size of numeric columns)
> + (length of strings)
> + (number of NULL columns + 7) / 8
> ```

Comment: But for storing a string that is mostly a char or varchar we have some  overhead in row store databases. Did you consider that in your reasoning?

Comment: If it's a VARCHAR, you'll probably need a byte or two telling the size of the value. *In addition* to this you'll need one bit to tell if it is NULL or not. You are correct that it should be possible to save ONLY the NULL bit for those columns and skip the string length bytes, but I don't know what way is most common. For fixed-length rows (like in some MyISAM tables) you'll really need that extra bit.